# Change Wordpress DB OR Table_Prefix On the Fly

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently running a website with TWO wordpess installs.

My first install is running off the root domain, www.mysite.com - I will refer to this Wordpress install as my "Core Installation"

My second install is running off a sub directory, www.mysite.com/mysubdir - I will refer to this Wordpress install as my "Sub Installation"

What i'm trying to accomplish is showing my Wordpress menu from my Core Installation on my Sub Installation.

I have both wordpress installs running off the same database, with different table prefixes.

The reason i'm hoping to run my Wordpress Menu from my Core Installation on my Sub Installation is so that I only have to update the Menu in one spot and the changes will be reflected on both installations.

I have attempted this coding in the following manner with no success:

$table_prefix  = 'wp_'; 
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Header Menu' )); 
$table_prefix  = 'dir_';

My theory behind this was to change the table_prefix that the system uses to the "Core Installation" prefix, output the menu, then switch it back to "Sub Installation"

I hope this makes sense.... I'm really stuck on this one and would appreciate the help VERY much.

Thanks

Loren

Answer (score 0):

I have never use this as you are trying to do, but the `$table_prefix` is set as a property of a wp-db instance, and to change it you call:

```
$wpdb->set_prefix( $table_prefix, $set_table_names = false );
```

But, as I said, I haven't tested it for your purposes.